# IntelliJ auto detect indentation for each file

Tags: intellij-idea, sublimetext2, indentation

I recently switched from Sublime Text to IntelliJ and I trying to figure out, if there's a way for IntelliJ to auto detect what indentation the current file is using and use that instead of the default

I have to deal with a lot of 3rd party code, which can have different indentation settings, which I'm not allowed to change for obvious reasons.

Sublime Text was able to detect and abide to the indentation for the current file, which is quite intuitive and unobtrusive. IntelliJ on the other hand just sticks to it's own settings, resulting in mixed tabs and spaces, wrong indentation levels and wrong merge conflicts.

Is there a way to make IntelliJ behave, other than having to manually change the indentation settings every time I get a file with different indentation.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In recent versions of Intellij there is a **Detect and use existing file indents for editing** setting for this:

[image]

Comment: i asked this question over 5 years ago and have long moved away from intellij. In any case, it's good to see they actually implemented this feature

Comment: I've tried `adam` `sublime` `vscode`  but always end up back in intellij. No it is not perfect: in particular _macros_ support is essentially useless.

Answer (score 2):

Each project you open in IntelliJ has it's own settings. You will need to set the indent style the first time you open up the project, but it will be saved after that (and can be different for every project you work on). From the [IntelliJ help site](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/project-and-ide-settings.html):

> Project settings are stored with each specific project as a set of `xml` files 
>   under the `.idea` folder. If you specify the 
>   [default project settings](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/accessing-default-project-settings-and-structure.html), 
>   these settings will be automatically used for each newly created project.

You can edit the indent settings for the project in the [Code Style dialog](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/code-style-java.html#d29504e350).

Comment: It doesn't really solve my problem, since I have multiple indent styles in the same project, but I got the same answer from jetbrains support, so I will take it

Comment: Grr, the styles aren't even consistent within a single project? Are they at least consistent between type of file (e.g. programming language)? If that was the case, you could at least set a default style for each type... Sorry that there isn't a better solution.

Comment: As I explained in my question, there's a lot of 3rd party code from clients and I cannot dictate what indent style they use

Comment: "aren't even consident within a single project" : it was  a core aspect of the question that he is referring to third party code. Even so I agree with the OP the contents of this answer are useful since they reflect the "state of the nation" wrt Intellij support for indentation,